# how to update the nested form in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi i created a form in react.js as follows

```
this.state = {
            name: '',
            subCatagory: [{ name: '', price: '', customize: [] }],
        };
```

my form as follows :

```
<form>
                <h4>Hotel Name</h4>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Hotel Name"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleMainItemNameChange}
                />

                <h4>subCatagory</h4>

                {this.state.subCatagory.map((subCatagory, idx) => (
                    <div className="subCatagory" key={idx}>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder={`Enter Dish  #${idx + 1} name`}
                            value={subCatagory.name}
                            onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryNameChange(idx)}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            placeholder={`subCatagory #${idx + 1} price`}
                            value={subCatagory.price}
                            onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryPriceChange(idx)}
                        />
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            onClick={this.handleRemovesubCatagory(idx)}
                            className="small"
                        >
                            Delete
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" onClick={this.addNewCust(idx)} className="small">
                            is cust availble?
                        </button>
                        {subCatagory.customize.map((gj, idx) => (
                            <div key={idx}>
                                <input
                                    type="number"
                                    placeholder={`subCatagory #${idx + 1} price`}
                                    value={gj.name}
                                    key={gj.key}
                                    onChange={this.gjj(idx)}
                                />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                ))}
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAddsubCatagory} className="small">
                    Add new Subcat
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                    Add menu to item
                </button>
            </form>
```

here i used map fuction to renderthe inputs when we add a new subCatagory a new json will add and as well as for the inputs they are getting updated but when i add new subCatagory --> customize the value are not updating in subCatagory -->  customize

my gist https://gist.github.com/gjgit/d8da23cfb08b73513b0b7aae758b8503

Comment: What does `console.log` with `gjj()` print when you change input value? And since you are not updating state in `gjj()`, you won't see changes reflected input.

Comment: yes ., my problem was when i change the value it have to push to that input